# Open pdf from hyperlink in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

want to open pdf file when a user clicks on hyperlink shown in gridview column.The name of the file is taken from first column of the gridview where file titles are stored.

hovering over hyperlink in gridview shows file link, but when clicked it doesnot open pdf file,

```
protected void Gridview1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{

 if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            HyperLink hlink = (HyperLink)e.Row.FindControl("HL");
            string url = "~/Docs/" + e.Row.Cells[1].Text +".pdf";
            hlink.NavigateUrl = url;
            hlink.Text = "Read";
        } 
 }
```

The following error comes when hyperlink is clicked, as it is not able to open pdf file.

> The resource cannot be found. 
>   Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable

which event is called when hyperlink is clicked in a gridview, maybe pdf application is to be opened there. Please suggest. Thanks in adavance.

Comment: Are you absolutely positive that the file being linked to is in that location?  Try putting debug output of `Server.MapPath(url);` and making sure the physical file location matches

Comment: iam sure file is there....i even put full path of the file...still same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error suggests that your file doesn't exist.  What you should do is to forego the concatenation that you do and instead include the whole name of the file (including extension) in your data source and use it (or even the entire path).  The reason you want to do it that way is because you may have modified/formatted/encoded the cell text strictly for aesthetic purposes.  You could have even added some embedded html to style it.

I would imagine it would look something like this:

```
protected void Gridview1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{

 if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
     {
            DataRow row = ((System.Data.DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem).Row;
            HyperLink hlink = e.Row.FindControl("HL") as HyperLink;
            if (hlink!=null)
            {
                string url = string.Format("~/Docs/{0}",row["FileName"]);
                hlink.NavigateUrl = url;
                hlink.Text = "Read";
            }
     } 
}
```

Comment: Good suggestion on storing whole file name.

Comment: working on your suggestions, i worked in three steps, first i implemented as it is what you have suggested.   second,  i added ".pdf" to the url.   third, i hard coded whole file path. same error,  " the resource cannot be found".    i have file in the same location.   i feel pdf application has to be called somehow to open pdf file as it shows " The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable" ......the depenedecies....

Comment: Interesting.  What I would do in that case @Sumit is to view the source of the page then observe the link.  In looking at the link, see if you notice any anomalies.  There is a problem somewhere in your path OR the file doesn't exist on the server.  Copy the path to your clipboard and paste it into the browser and see what happens.  It should do the exact same thing, only doing it that way may get you to see something you didn't before.

Comment: @ jeremy calling the path in browser opens pdf file perfectly as you must be expecting. But in code, hard coding the complete path isn't opening the file. same error.  when i hard code the complete path, the hyperlink stops working infact.

Comment: Fascinating!  Would you mind posting the path?  I'm wondering if there are any encoding issues.  I think as another troubleshooting exercise, you could make your link refer to a different file type (like txt), and to make it a simple file name without spaces to see if you get any change.

Comment: the path in clipboard is C:\Users\Documents\Projects\WebSite1\Docs\MD.pdf

Comment: K, your link shouldn't look like that.  You should be seeing something like:  `http:\\<mysite>\docs\md.pdf` which you should have gotten if your code used this: `~/Docs/md.pdf`.

Comment: localhost/WebSite1/Docs/MD.pdf in case when i code  string url = string.Format("~//Docs//MD.pdf");  and as i told when i put complete path, the path in the browser is shown as same complete path as shown in previous comment but hyperlink stops working...i mean clicking doesnt do anything

Comment: so jeremy finally i got it working. there were two mistakes. one the path was incorrect. and gridview was adding extra white spaces in the path so i trimmed the string. thx for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried checking the "View Source" in the browser on this page to check the actual path of the link that is being outputted and verify it is correct?
Have you stepped through the debugger to make sure that `FindControl("HL");` is actually finding the control you are looking for? Since the control is in a GridView, asp.net might have modified its `id`. You can try getting the `HL` control using

```
HyperLink hlink = e.Row.Cells[HL_cell_index].Controls[HL_control_index] as HyperLink;
```

if you are having issues there. One of those two things must be your problem.

As a suggestion, in agreement with @Jeremy, you should also store the full path of the file in your data source (be it database or whatever you are using) to bind to this hyperlink column, so that you don't have to do this extra event binding and run into issues like this.